# Issue with CLOSE_WAIT status

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I see a number of connections with CLOSE_WAIT status on my production server, and there are few questions. Please advice.

1. I know that the windows register has the following parameter:

**TcpTimedWaitDelay** in the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters**

According to the Microsoft stuff (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2networking/thread/4288d218-fbf9-4489-b869-384a05dea83d/) , the value of the TIME_WAIT by default is 4 minutes. I set up the value in 30 seconds, but it looks like nothing is changed. Moreover, even after 4 mins CLOSE_WAIT connections are still there.

My questions is how I can change the value of the TIME_WAIT, and see it in action? Should I restart my server?

1. Is there any other settings to control the CLOSE_WAIT status in the Windows environment?

Regards,
Cyril

Comment: Thanks, I know it. TcpTimedWaitDelay is related to TIME_WAIT, and TIME_WAIT is related to CLOSE_WAIT. Isn't it?

Comment: no, they are completely different states, see the state diagram in page 23 of RFC793: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `CLOSE_WAIT` and `TIME_WAIT`. They're not the same.

See here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html for some details on TIME_WAIT and why you might not really want to play with shortening the timeout.

And see here: http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/summaries/2006-January/007068.html and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/10/09/tcp-connections-hanging-in-the-close-wait-and-fin-wait-2-state.aspx for details on why you might be collecting sockets stuck in `CLOSE_WAIT` - in summary, you're possibly not closing your sockets correctly.

Comment: The peer has closed, the local application hasn't.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 6):

CLOSE_WAIT means that the peer has closed the connection and you haven't. The operating system is waiting for *you* (the local application) to close it.

So close it. Somewhere or other you have missed out.

Answer (score 0):

I Will suggest you to use Spring WS because I was facing same issue in my project and I switched to Spring Web Service than my problem resolved.

See the following code,

```
<bean id="viewCustomerInfo"
class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean"
p:serviceInterface="com.javaplex.CustomerInfoInterface"
p:wsdlDocumentUrl="http://127.0.0.1:8080/portal/CustomerInfoPort?wsdl"
p:namespaceUri="http://ws.customergen.com/" p:serviceName="CustomerInfo"
p:portName="CustomerInfoPort">
```

here is the complete article how to setup spring based beans which give your optimum performance.

http://www.javaplex.com/spring-jax-ws-client-for-best-performance/